# Finding Closest Label without being too specific

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT**

Essentially what I am trying to do is solve "Nearest (previous)" "First" "Label" to a specific class on an input without adding additional markup. Please view my fiddle below to see a few cases. I am aware I can add css etc. to this.. I am looking for a JS solution.

**END EDIT**

Fiddle Provided below.

I am trying to find a corresponding (previous) label to a class - in multiple use cases - I do not what the HTML to have to be too strict - I'd like to be a able to use this in a variety of solutions...

```
$(".FINDME")
    .siblings("label")
    .prepend("<span style='color: magenta;'>* </span>");
```

The previous works, but not for all instances where the label may not be a sibling or when there are nested divs.

I also tried:

```
$(".FINDME")
    .closest(".row")
    .find("label")
    .append("<span style='color: magenta;'> *</span>");
```

this works as well but in the case when there are multiple labels in the `.row` this applies the * to all labels.

I need a solution to find the nearest label to the class.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/r6Lx4ytg/

Comment: Use attributes to match target label to `.FINDME`. There is no one size fits all without some way to match them

Comment: Your question is too open-ended. You're asking us to come up with a selector for endless possibilities. Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: You'll have to define 'nearest' so people know whether parent, child or sibling is 'nearest'

Comment: You'll see the working example better in the fiddle. I was hoping there was a better way to find the nearest label without having to add additional markup or consistent markup. (IE: using this for various cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question :)

I tried to solve this, by considering input control as a center and each time increasing the radius where I search for a label.

If I don't find a label within the current parent object, then I take parent's parent (ancestor), and this goes on till it reach maximum depth.

```js
// comment out either one to see the difference:
//$(".FINDME").siblings("label").prepend("<span style='color: magenta;'>* </span>");
//$(".FINDME").closest(".row").find("label").append("<span style='color: magenta;'> *</span>");

$(".FINDME").each(function(idx, obj) {
  var $obj = $(obj);
  var parent = $obj;
  var depth = 5, // You can define till which depth you can test for nearest label
    currentDepth = 0;
  while (true) {
    parent = parent.parent();
    currentDepth++;
    if (!parent || currentDepth == depth)
      break;
    var labels = parent.find("label");
    if (labels.length > 0) {
      var myLabel = $(labels[0]);
      if (myLabel.find(".star").length == 0)
        myLabel.prepend("<span class='star' style='color: magenta;'>* </span>");
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.row .col-md-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66666666666667%;
}
.row .col-md-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.row .col-md-10 {
  float: left;
  width: 83.33333333333333%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>First Name:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" value="" class="FINDME" placeholder="First Name" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <label>Middle Name:</label>
  <input type="text" value="" class="FINDME" placeholder="Middle Name" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" value="" class="FINDME" placeholder="Last Name" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <br>
    <div class="FINDME">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="alien">Alien
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Food:</label>
    <div class="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk">Milk
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter">Butter
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese">Cheese
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/8xqzupwe/6/

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting solution - the one caveat I will mention - Not all labels should get the * - if the associated class "FINDME" does not exist the previous label shouldn't get it. I like your solution and think with some tweaking it may be perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @remixdesign I've tweaked the input selector to just find label for the input with .FINDME. Hope this helps.

Comment: works great on everything but the gender and food.. if you remove the class .FINDME from the checkbox grouping - it still gets the added * - this is because it's finding it as a sibling still - I think we are close though! Thank you again for your help

Comment: @remixdesign if 'div' has 'FINDME' then should the label nearest to that should be prepended with '*' ? OR is it just for input

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/57tnczu4/

I added some comments to tell what should happen..

Comment: This should cover your case ... https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/57tnczu4/1/

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are using javascript? A simple solution with css would be

```
.required::after {
  content: "*";
  color: magenta;
}
```

Then you can just put a class of `required` on labels that you want to have an asterik

Comment: @charlietfl hence why I asked is there a reason why he is doing it that way? Maybe he didn't know there was other solutions.

Comment: I actually like this approach better as well. OP's markup is not consistent so we can't write a single selector for it. He would need to add conditional logic.

Comment: You'll see the working example better in the fiddle. I was hoping there was a better way to find the nearest label without having to add additional markup. (IE: using this for various cases) - I know I can do it with pure css. I am sorry I wasnt clear enough in the question.